# databases design

Tags: database, database-design

for example i have table `users`, which have 3 fields:

```
id - login - password
---------------------
1  | john   |  *****
2  | jack   |  *****
3  | jane   |  *****
```

now i want that each user could have his own settings.
So, do i need to create three different tables, like

`user_N_settings`:

```
id |  key        | value
-------------------------
1  | save_data   | True
```

or i should create one big table for all users instead?

`users_settings`:

```
id     | key       |    value   |    user_id
---------------------------------------------
1      | save_data |   True     |        2
2      | some_opt  |   False    |        3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One table for all users.  A table per user would be **very** wrong.

Comment: even if i have hundreads `key`-`value`'s for thousand's users?

Comment: @cru31 yes, ESPECIALLY if you have 1000s of users.

Answer (score 2):

One table. If all the setting values are of the same type then it may make sense to create one row per setting. If the attributes are all very different then create one column per setting.